# react es6 server side rendering doesn't require a factory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was writing an app with react and to perform server-side rendering I did the following:

```
var Component = require('myComponent');
var ComponentFactory = React.createFactory(Component);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        react: ReactDom.renderToString(ComponentFactory()),
    });
});
```

Now I'm rewriting the app but switched most of the javascript to ES6, but when I tried to create a factory with the component, it would not show up in the browser, instead I had to do the following:

```
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        reacthtml: ReactDom.renderToString(<InfoBoxes />)***here***
    });
});
```

I had to just input the component in jsx syntax. Is this ES6 dependent or is there another reason why this may happen?

Comment: There's not enough information here to say why this is happening. But you have another difference between the two examples: `react:` vs `reacthtml:`. I also wonder if `myComponent` has been transpiled from ES6 module syntax and if so how and if you need to do `require('myComponent').default`.

Comment: @JMM `I'm rewriting the app but switched most of...` generally that means the app was not written in ES6, that's why I'm switching. Therefore myComponent has not been transpired from ES6

Comment: If you want help you should just clearly explain the situation. "switched most of the javascript to ES6" past tense suggests a strong possibility that `myComponent` is being transpiled from ES6. The only way I know it's not is via your comment, which implies that that conclusion logically follows from the question, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX like this:

```
<InfoBoxes />
```

Is actually transpiled into this:

```
React.createElement(InfoBoxes)
```

And `createFactory` looks (roughly) like this:

```
function createFactory(type) {
    return React.createElement.bind(null, type);
}
```

So they are ultimately equivalent; you don't need to use factories if you're using jsx.